# Variance inflation factor

Tags: time-series, stationarity, variance-inflation-factor

I am trying out VIF in order to reduce the number of variables, by removing highly collinear variables. I will be using VIF in R, but before applying it, does my time series need to be stationary?I cant seem to find a list of its prerequisites. I am currently using principal component analysis and I want to cross it with VIF.

Comment: What is the model for your time series?  Normally VIF is a measure of how much the collinearity affects the variance of regression coefficients.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, As far as I can tell, VIF only holds its strict interpretation in linear regression models, but I've seen published papers use it for non-linear models like logistic or poisson regression. Is that valid?

Comment: @not_bonferroni I think VIF is a broad concept that can be defined to measure the effect of collinearity on the variability of regression coefficients in nonlinear regression as you indicate. I am not familiar with these articles so I don't actually know how it is generalized. Somehow it has to be linked to the dependent variable.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I am using VAR, will that do?thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't know python.  I am more of a python novice than you are.  Am I right to assume VAR is python software?

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I mean Vector Autoregressions(VAR) model to approxiamte my dependent variable. So, what I am trying to do is a multivariate time series forcasting using VAR but I have thousands of variables so I wanted to use VIF together with PCA to correctly reduce the number of variables. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelChernick can I use VIF even if my time series variables are non stationary?

Comment: *"does my time series need to be stationary?"* This depends on the type of problem. Without an introduction about the background it is unclear to say. The relationship between VIF and time series is unclear, compare with a question like *"I am trying to make a menu with vegetables, fish and meat. Do I need roses or tulips for the decoration?"*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about time series, but VIF is only about the independent variables. I also wonder about what it means to "cross" VIF with PCA. PCA can be one way to deal with collinearity; VIF is a method of diagnosing it.

[Mathworks Time Series Regression II](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/time-series-regression-ii-collinearity-and-estimator-variance.html) is all about dealing with collinearity in time series. They recommend condition indexes, rather than VIF, and say a $\kappa$ of 100 or so "eads to absolute estimation errors ‖δβ‖ that are approximated by the relative errors in the data."  (In my dissertation, I found that condition indexes were better than VIF for regular regression, echoing Belsley in his book on this).  MathWorks does discuss VIF and points out some difficulties, although they don't seem insurmountable.